# Powershell command returns empty string

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm trying to execute the 'set location' command in Powershell. I need to get the new location as the output.

But when I check p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); it returns an empty string. How do I get the new location from standard out put?

```
 public static void ExecutePoweshell(Process p, string workingDirectory, string Command)
        {           
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;

            var psCommandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Command);
            var psCommandBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(psCommandBytes);
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -EncodedCommand {psCommandBase64}"; 
            
            p.Start();

            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(Command);
            p.StandardInput.Flush();
            p.StandardInput.Close();

            string outputtext = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

> Method will be used as below:

```
Process p = new Process()
ExecutePoweshell(p, @"C:\Windows\SYSTEM32", @"Set-Location -Path C:\")
```

Comment: IIRC `Set-Location` does not really return anything in standard output. Just that. Try with `Get-ChildItem C:\ ` instead.

Comment: Your post is showing you are hard coding the path, so, why send it back, since you already know what it's going to be? yet, anyway, you can get it, but you have to tell it to. That is what -PassThru is for.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing to from my comment:

To get Set-Location to return anything, you must do something like this:

```
Set-Location -Path 'C:\Scripts\' -PassThru

# Results
<#
Path
----
C:\Scripts
#>
```

Or this...

```
(Set-Location -Path 'C:\Scripts\' -PassThru).Path
# Results
<#
C:\Scripts
#>
```

Or this...

```
 # Using variable squeezing to assign to the variable and output to the screen simultaneously.

($NewLocation = (Set-Location -Path 'C:\Scripts\' -PassThru).Path)
# Results
<#
C:\Scripts
#>
```